# Simple mars rover example

Tags: java, iteration, java.util.scanner

The robot starts from coordinates (0,0) while pointing in the north direction.

- User input = string such as LRLRLLFRRFRLRF. Here L = point left, R =
  point right, F = move forward one unit.
- Output = (5,6) = final
  coordinates of the robot.

I am using Java Scanner class to get input from user. But the output is blank.
Here is my complete code:

```
public static void printLocation() {

//      index 0 = North, index 1 = East, index 2 = South, index 3 = West

    System.out.println("Enter the sequence"); //eg - LRFFRRLRLF
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    int index=0, x=0, y=0;

    while(scan.hasNext()) {

        String token = scan.next();
        if(token.equals("R")) {
            index=index+1;
        }
        if(token.equals("L")) {
            index=index-1;
        }

        if(index > 3 && index%3 !=0) {
            index = index%3-1;
        }
        else if(index > 3 && index%3 == 0) {
            index = 3;
        }

        if(token.equals("F")) {
            if(index == 0) {
                y=y+1;
            }
            if(index == 1) {
                x=x+1;
            }
            if(index == 2) {
                y=y-1;
            }
            if(index == 3) {
                x=x-1;
            }
        }
    }
    System.out.println("("+x+","+y+")");
}
```

What am I doing wrong ? A little help please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your output is blank, because the program expects another input to enter when you use `scan.hasNext()`. One of the ways is to read the whole string using `scan.nextLine()`, convert it to char array and then parse it symbol by symbol.

```
public static void printLocation() {

    // index 0 = North, index 1 = East, index 2 = South, index 3 = West
    System.out.println("Enter the sequence"); //eg - LRFFRRLRLF
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    String sequence = scan.nextLine();

    char[] sequenceArray = sequence.toCharArray();

    int index = 0, x = 0, y = 0;
    int i = 0;
    while (i < sequenceArray.length) {       

        String token = String.valueOf(sequenceArray[i]);
        i++;

        if (token.equals("R")) {
            index = index + 1;
        }
        if (token.equals("L")) {
            index = index - 1;
        }           

        if (index > 3 && index % 3 != 0) {
            index = index % 3 - 1;
        } else if (index > 3 && index % 3 == 0) {
            index = 3;
        }

        if (token.equals("F")) {
            if (index == 0) {
                y = y + 1;
            }
            if (index == 1) {
                x = x + 1;
            }
            if (index == 2) {
                y = y - 1;
            }
            if (index == 3) {
                x = x - 1;
            }
        }            
    }
    System.out.println("(" + x + "," + y + ")");
}
```

However, you should check to logic of your code yourself. I can't be sure it is correct. If you enter `LRLRLLFRRFRLRF`, the output will be (1,1). So test it yourself.

Comment: Yes. I understand that now. Parsing the input string was the main issue. I fixed it. Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 1):

You need to read the contents of the entered string like this

```
String pathSequence = sc.next();
```

And then iterate over each letter in the string pathSequence